# DB2 SQL Find department numbers having the same first and last hiring date as deptno 10 and count the years

Tags: sql, join, count, db2, aggregate-functions

Find departments which hired also the same year as department 10 did. Suppose department 10 hires every year. Use aggregate functions and the year function.

This is my SQL:

```
  select a.deptno, year(a.hiredate) as first, year(b.hiredate) as last, count (*) as num
  from 
  (select d.deptno, h.hiredate, count(h.hiredate)
  from emp as d
  inner join emp as h on
  d.deptno=d.deptno
  where d.deptno = 10 
  group by d.deptno, h.hiredate
  having count (d.deptno)>1
  order by h.hiredate asc
  limit 1) as a

  inner join 

  (select d.deptno, h.hiredate, count(h.hiredate)
  from emp as d
  inner join emp as h on
  d.deptno=h.deptno
  where d.deptno = 10 
  group by d.deptno, h.hiredate
  having count (d.deptno)>1
  order by h.hiredate desc
  limit 1) as b
  on a.deptno=b.deptno
  group by a.deptno, a.hiredate, b.hiredate;
```

And this is the result from my SQL:

```
 deptno  first  last  num
---------------------------
 10      1980   1982   1
```

I have tried different things like for example adding  **d.deptno=10 and d.deptno<>10** but then the result is blank. And also how to get the right count from the two joins?
I would be very happy, if someone could help me.

**Here is my table, if someone wants to test it:**

```
 create table emp(
 EMPNO int,
 ENAME varchar(10),
 JOB varchar(20),
 MGR varchar(20),
 HIREDATE date,
 SAL float,
 COM varchar(20),
 DEPTNO int
 );




insert into emp values (7839, 'KING', 'President', '-' , '1981-11-17', 5000.00,'-',10);
insert into emp values(7698, 'BLAKE', 'Manager', 7839, '1981-05-01', 2850.00, '-', 30);
insert into emp values(7782, 'CLARK', 'Manager', 7839, '1981-06-09', 2450.00,'-', 10);
insert into emp values(7756, 'JONES', 'Manager', 7839, '1981-04-02', 2975.00, '-', 20);
insert into emp values(7788, 'SCOTT', 'Analyst', 7566, '1987-04-19', 3000.00, '-', 20);
insert into emp values(7902, 'FORD', 'Analyst', 7566, '1982-02-26', 3000.00, '-', 20);
insert into emp values(7369, 'SMITH', 'Clerk', 7902, '1980-12-17', 800.00, '-', 20);
insert into emp values(7499, 'ALLEN', 'Salesman', 7698, '1981-02-20', 1600.00, 300.00, 30);
insert into emp values(7521,'WARD', 'Salesman', 7698, '1981-02-22', 1250.00, 500.00, 30);
insert into emp values(7654, 'MARTIN', 'Salesman', 7698, '1981-09-28', 1250.00, 1400.00, 30);
insert into emp values(7844, 'TURNER', 'Salesman', 7698, '1981-09-08', 1500.00, 0.00, 30);
insert into emp values(7876, 'ADAMS', 'Clerk', 7798, '1987-05-23', 1100.00, '-', 20);
insert into emp values(7900, 'JAMES', 'Clerk', 7698, '1981-12-03', 950.00, '-', 30);
insert into emp values(7934, 'MILLER', 'Clerk', 7782, '1982-01-23', 1300.00, '-',10);
```

**And this is the correct result, that should be showing:**

```
 deptno  first  last  num
---------------------------
 10      1981   1982   2
 20      1981   1982   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you could solve this with a common table expression that computes the first and last hire year for each departement, and then a self-join that filters in departments that have the same first and last hire date as departement 10:

```
with depts as (
    select 
        deptno, 
        year(min(hiredate)) first_hire_year, 
        year(max(hiredate)) last_hire_year,
        count(*) total_hires
    from emp
    group by deptno
)
select d.*
from depts d
inner join depts d10
    on  d10.deptno = 10
    and d10.first_hire_year = d.first_hire_year
    and d10.last_hire_year = d.last_hire_year
```

---

On the other hand, if you are looking to pull out all departments that, for each year when department 10 did hire, also hired, that is a bit different. I would generate a list of all years when department 10 did hire, combine it with the list of departments, and then eliminate those that did not match, as follows:

```
select 
    d.deptno, 
    min(y.hire_year) first_hire_year,
    max(y.hire_year) last_hire_year,
    count(d.deptno) count_hire_year
from 
    (select distinct year(hiredate) hire_year from emp where deptno = 10) y
    cross join (select distinct deptno from emp) d
    left join (select distinct deptno, year(hiredate) hire_year from emp) e
        on  e.hire_year = y.hire_year
        and e.deptno = d.deptno
group by d.deptno
having count(d.deptno) = count(e.deptno)
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a3bd29919c6aa54bfd085f3524450287)**, the second query yields:

```
DEPTNO | FIRST_HIRE_YEAR | LAST_HIRE_YEAR | COUNT_HIRE_YEAR
-----: | --------------: | -------------: | --------------:
    10 |            1981 |           1982 |               2
    20 |            1981 |           1982 |               2
```

Comment: Hello, i tested your code, and I'm still having the result only for dept10, other departments hired as department 10 are missing. And the count should count the years. I have already showed, how the result should look like. And i haven't learned about table expressions, so im not so sure if I'm allowed to use them.

Comment: @xamsas: would you please edit your question to provide some sample data that we could play around with to test the query, along with the results that you would expect for the test dataset?

Comment: yes i have done that, you can see the table i used and the correct result @GMB

Comment: Thank you @xamsas. It your dataset, there is no department that has the same *first* and *last* hire year than department 10.  Dept 10 has 1981 and 1982, dept 20 has 1980 and 1987, dept 30 has 1981 only.

Comment: You are not looking correctly, dept 20 has 1980, 1981, 1982 and 1987 @GMB

Comment: @xamsas: ok I think I see what you mean now. I edited my answer with anoter query, that produces the expected results.

Comment: Thank you!! @GMB